# Does anyone know how to attach a script to Ektron's Upload button?

Tags: image, amazon-s3, upload, ektron

I want to attach a script to the upload button in Ektron so that whenever someone uploads an image, the image is sent to our S3 account to be stored. Does anyone know how to hack into Ektron's upload function?

Answer (score 1):

No need to "hack", you can just use a content strategy.  This will allow you to run custom code following an event in the CMS.  You can use the OnAfterPublishContent() strategy, then run some C# code to move the document into S3.

Please see the [Ektron documentation](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.10/Reference/Web/EktronReferenceWeb.html#Developer/extension.htm?Highlight=strategy) for more info

Comment: Does OnAfterPublishContent() work for saving images to the library? I've attached to the process but the override function doesn't seem to be getting hit.

Comment: OnAfterPublishContent will work for managed assets.  If you want to add items to the Library you should use a LibraryStrategy called OnAfterAdd().  Again this can be found in the documentation under LibraryStrategies.